# Optimizing .NET function in terms of search index usage

Tags: .net, arrays, performance, search, optimization

I have a function I wrote to search an array for occurrence of a particular word. The function take in an array of lines of text and a target keyword it has to search for and returns an arraylist of ines containing the target word. For instance if array is (each line is array's subscript):

testing .net application
the big brown cat
sample application
search index optimization
search for the cat
big pink elephant

and the function call is FindLinesInArray(arr, "cat"), then the function would return and array list with two lines:

the big brown cat
search for the cat

The function is as follows:

```
Function FindLinesInArray(ByRef arr() As String, ByVal target As String) As ArrayList
    Dim idx As Integer
    Dim temp As String = ""
    Dim alist As ArrayList = New ArrayList()

    Try
        For idx = 0 To arr.Length - 1
            If arr(idx).ToString().ToLower().IndexOf(target) <> -1 Then
                temp = arr(idx).ToString().ToLower().Trim()
                alist.Add(temp)
            End If
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message & " - " & ex.StackTrace)
    End Try

    Return alist

End Function
```

My question is how can I optimize this function in terms of a usage of the search index. The program I am running calls this function a number of times on large arrays and I was wondering if there is a better way to do this

Comment: Do you have many different large arrays to search for? Or do you have always the same array to search for many different targets?

Comment: basically I have a number of different large arrays and one small array of search values. In my example I used to search term "cat" but there is actually a whole array of 5 or more variations of the word "cat" to search for. It could be "cat", or "cats" or "c at" or 
"ca ts" or "cat s" just to give you an example. So I have an array arrtarget as string()={"cat","cats","c at", "ca ts", "cat s"}  and then a number of large arrays and I need to search each of those large arrays and find all the lines that contain any variations of the word "cat"

Answer (score -1):

This is c#
I did it from memory so it probably has some syntax errors

```
public class SearchLine 
{
    private HashSet<string> words;
    public void ContainsWords (HashSet<string> FindWords)
    {
        if (words == null)
        {
            words = new HashSet<string>();
            foreach (string s in Line.Split(" "))
            {
               if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
                  words.Add(s.Trim());
            }
        }
        return FindWords.Overlaps(words);
    }
    public string Line { get; private set;
    public SearchLine(string line) 
    {
        Line = line;
    }
}
```

Comment: The input has to be an array not hashset. I need to improve existing code

Comment: Just why in the world does the input need to be an array rather than a hashset?   It is a set of words to match.   HashSet Overlaps is smoking fast - array does not have Overlaps.   You can create a HashSet from an array.

Comment: Because that is something I cannot change. I have to work with what I have, which is an array

Comment: Really, you are not allowed to create an array of SearchLine?   SearchLine takes string as a ctor.   Why would you not test for a whole set of words at once (fast) rather than one at a time?

Comment: Blam, I am asking if there is a way to improve my code that I poseted